# How to make this network config code to scale for many devices?

Tags: python, networking, scalability

More looking for suggestions here.
I am working on some code (snippet below) to fetch, edit, and optimise some configuration on a number of network devices. 
I need to address more than 1000 devices, various types, and need to make this work quite efficient. 
So understand multiprocessing, using generators, etc can help, but not quite clear where how I should apply those in such a class structure I have?

```
class Device_optimiser():
    @staticmethod
    def connector(**args):
        ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        for i in args["devices"]:
            try:
                ssh_client.connect(hostname= i['host'],
                                   username=args['username'],
                                   password=args['password'],
                                   port = 22)
            except Exception:
                ll.error("bad device")
            stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(i['command'])
            return stdout.read()

    @staticmethod
    def parser(msg):
        parsed_msg = msg + "some work"
        return parsed_msg

    @staticmethod
    def algorithm(parsed_msg):
        sort_selected_msg = parsed_msg + "some work"
        return sort_selected_msg

    @classmethod
    def main(cls, info):
        ssh_output = Device_optimiser.connector(**info)
        parsed_output = Device_optimiser.parser(ssh_output)
        Device_optimiser.algorithm(parsed_output)
        Device_optimiser.connector(**info)
```

Comment: You never used `__init__` or `self` but you are using every method (wrongly) as a class method. Why do you have a class then and not just functions?

Comment: I made a quick update. The class implementation now uses static methods. The class is a wrapper here for relevant functions. And also I may add more attributes to it. My focus now  is to share the structure, and get opinions on how to make this very scalable and fast at the same time

Comment: To say it short: Python is not Java.